# Why is py linked to __main__.py and not python3?

Tags: python, symlink

I've recently moved from Windows to Ubuntu in a container.

From Windows I'm used to running

```
$ py myScript.py
```

However this wasn't working as expected in Ubuntu, so have been using

```
$ python3 myScript.py
```

To update `py` to work as I expect, I looked into `/usr/bin` to get more information, I get the output:

```
...
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          38 May 22  2016  py -> ../share/pythonpy/pythonpy/__main__.py
...
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root           9 Mar 13  2020  python3 -> python3.8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root     5502744 Jun 22 21:18  python3.8    
...
```

What is `__main__.py` that `py` has been linked to? Is this normal? Can I update the link to point to `python3` or do I need to learn more about the distinctions between `py` and `python3`?

Comment: It looks like you have this package installed: https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/pythonpy the symlink points to this, not python itself.  Looks like the `py` command you are looking for is a windows thing: https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows Generally you should be fine if you just sym link `py` to `python`.

Comment: @PhilipCouling I was in the man page for it at https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/py.1.html

Looks like it interprets a single line. I don't need that at the moment. Looks like a job for `apt-get remove pythonpy` and then learning about symlinks!

Comment: Sure. Symlinks in general can be created with `ln -s` see `man ln`. However these particular ones might be created via [update-alternatives](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/update-alternatives.1.html#:~:text=update%2Dalternatives%20creates%2C%20removes%2C,system%20at%20the%20same%20time.)

Comment: @PhilipCouling symlinks managed by `update-alternatives` point to links in `/etc/alternatives`; the symlinks here aren’t managed like that.

Comment: @StephenKitt Oh you are right. I wasn't thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the behaviour I was expecting and that I wanted with:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove pythonpy
```

then

```
$ sudo ln -s python3 py
```